# receiving an error when issued apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible

Tags: software-installation, ppa

I am installing Ansible on Ubuntu 16.04. When I issue the command

```
apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
```

the system is throwing this error message

```
cannot add PPA "ppa:~ansible/ubuntu/ansible
ERROR:'~ansible' user or team does not exists
```

Comment: still facing same issue even after issuing sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible command

Comment: Just added it to my system, open a new terminal and try copy and paste if you must

Answer (score 0):

The correct commands to add this repository would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: receiving same error still with above commands

Comment: @VikasNule contact the maintainer of the PPA at https://launchpad.net/%7Eansible/+contactuser , or possibly at jenkins@ansible.com